# QT C++ Signal & Slots with stacked widgets and two classes

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have been reading about SLOTS and SIGNALS in QT C++, however I have been having load of issues trying to understand how this works and how to make it work.

**my receiver class is**

```
#ifndef RECIEVER_H
#define RECIEVER_H

#include "sender.h"

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Reciever;
}

class Reciever : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Reciever(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Reciever();

private:
    Ui::Reciever *ui;
    Sender sender;

public slots:
    static void recive_message();


};

#endif // RECIEVER_H
```

**my Sender class is**

```
#ifndef SENDER_H
#define SENDER_H
#include <QWidget>


namespace Ui {
class Sender;
}

class Sender : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Sender(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Sender();

private slots:
    void on_Send_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Sender *ui;

};

#endif // SENDER_H
```

**My main window cpp file is**

```
#include "reciever.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Reciever w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Receiver cpp is**

```
#include "sender.h"
#include <QDebug>

Reciever::Reciever(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Reciever)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->stackedWidget->insertWidget(1, &sender);
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);

}

Reciever::~Reciever()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Reciever::recive_message()
{
    qDebug() << "signal recieved ";
    ui->label->setText("Got the  signal");
}
```

**and the sender cpp is**

```
#include "sender.h"
#include "ui_sender.h"
#include "reciever.h"

Sender::Sender(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Sender)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->Send, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(on_Send_cliked()));


}

Sender::~Sender()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Sender::on_Send_clicked()
{
    emit Reciever::recive_message();
}
```

I have tried all possible recommendations of the connect function i.e connect using on the sender.ccp.
I read the SIGNALS and Slots documentation, but is quite confusing for me (as I am not a native English speaker)

```cpp
Receiver *receiver = new Receiver;

connect (ui->Send, &QPushButton::clicked,receiver, Receiver::recive_message());
```

This method does gives me an segmentation fault.

```
1     _int_malloc                                                                                             malloc.c     3679 0x7ffff708be4e 
2     __GI___libc_malloc                                                                                      malloc.c     3066 0x7ffff708e299 
3     QArrayData::allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, QFlags<QArrayData::AllocationOption>)                   0x7ffff74ad241 
4     QByteArray::reallocData(unsigned int, QFlags<QArrayData::AllocationOption>)                                               0x7ffff74af3c9 
5     ??                                                                                                                        0x7ffff7671908 
6     ??                                                                                                                        0x7ffff7672159 
7     QMetaObject::normalizedSignature(const char *)                                                                            0x7ffff7678766 
8     QAccessibleWidget::addControllingSignal(QString const&)                                                                   0x7ffff7ce51fd 
9     ??                                                                                                                        0x7ffff7cf2e7f 
10    ??                                                                                                                        0x7ffff7ce6439 
11    QAccessible::queryAccessibleInterface(QObject *)                                                                          0x7ffff6afcca8 
12    QAccessibleEvent::accessibleInterface() const                                                                             0x7ffff6afd6e3 
13    QAccessible::updateAccessibility(QAccessibleEvent *)                                                                      0x7ffff6afdbe1 
14    QAbstractButton::setText(QString const&)                                                                                  0x7ffff7b8c014 
15    Ui_Sender::retranslateUi                                                                                ui_sender.h  46   0x555555559d9e 
16    Ui_Sender::setupUi                                                                                      ui_sender.h  38   0x555555559c36 
17    Sender::Sender                                                                                          sender.cpp   9    0x555555559910 
18    Reciever::Reciever                                                                                      reciever.cpp 8    0x5555555588bb 
19    Sender::Sender                                                                                          sender.cpp   11   0x55555555992a 
20    Reciever::Reciever                                                                                      reciever.cpp 8    0x5555555588bb 
21    Sender::Sender
```

Comment: `ui->label->setText("Got the  signal");` can't work in `void Reciever::recive_message()` if its a static member function. It shouldn't compile

Comment: Please stop using the old not-type-safe and slow at run time `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros. Modern Qt versions have nice type safe, compile time checked signals and slots - use those, not the old cruft.

Comment: @starball, Thanks, I just add the details from the debugger

Comment: @Harry01 I don't see your changes. Can you check to confirm you have actually edited your post?

Comment: sorry, I did not noticed that the text wasn't copied